# Postgres syntax error at or near "VALUESNSERT"

Tags: postgresql, informatica

We are trying to load the data from one postgres table to another postgres table in the same database using informatica. And we are having the following issue -

The error message is as follows:

```
Message Code: WRT_8229
Message: Database errors occurred: 
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver][PostgreSQL]ERROR: VERROR; syntax error at or near "VALUESNSERT"(Position 135; File scan.l; Line 1134; Routine scanner_yyerror; ) Error in parameter 6.
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver][PostgreSQL]Failed transaction. The current transaction rolled back. Error in parameter 6.
FnName: Execute -- [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Function sequence error
```

It is working fine if we are not loading one of the string column which is of 3000 bytes. Can anyone please shed some light on this issue -

Note: There are no reserved/keywords in our table structure

Comment: `VALUESNSERT` is an pretty obvious error. But without the code that generates the SQL this is impossible to answer

Comment: If you've got access to the database server files themselves, check the log file.  It will typically print include the SQL statement that failed and may provide more detail than you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already identified the error-causing column then, you can follow below steps to find the root cause -
1. You can check the data type of the column in informatica - if it is matching to the target in DB in terms of length and data type.
2. Make sure you import the target from database. Creating target from other process or adding column to existing target can lead to such error.
3. run in verbose mode or debug to see where exactly its causing issue. Check if its reading, transforming, and loading data properly etc.
4. remove postgres target and attach a flat file - if this works then there is issue in database table. Check for index, constraints etc. which can lead to this issue.
5. Check ODBC version as well which may have lots of limitations like data type, length handling. ODBC is also not good at generating errors so you may have to do some guesswork etc to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. My issue got resolved after implementing Informatica PDO.